# Predicate Logic - Using the 3 Rules

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have a question which I'm struggling to get to grips with.

Here are my predicates:

`Px = “x is a person”`

and

`Kxy = "x knows y's business"`

and the question is:

"Write the negation of the sentence ∀ x • ∀ y • Px ∧ Py ⇒ ¬ Kxy in a form
without any “¬ ” symbols, showing how you used the laws of logic to transform
it."

I know of the 3 rules: negation, implication, and de Morgan's Law. I've used these rules/ law(s) on  much simpler questions in the past however I'm not too sure on how to apply them to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negation of :

> $∀x ∀y (Px ∧ Py \to \lnot Kxy)$

is :

> $\lnot ∀x ∀y (Px ∧ Py \to \lnot Kxy)$.

Using the equivalence between $\lnot \forall$ and $\exists \lnot$, we can rewrite the last formula as :

> $\exists x \exists y \lnot (Px ∧ Py \to \lnot Kxy)$.

Now we apply the "propositional" equivalence between $\lnot(p \to q)$ and $(p \land \lnot q)$ to get :

> $\exists x \exists y (Px ∧ Py \land \lnot \lnot Kxy)$

and finally, by *double negation* :

> > $\exists x \exists y (Px ∧ Py \land Kxy)$.

Comment: Brill! Extremely well explained, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Turn the "implies" into an "or". Then the inside becomes $\neg Px\lor\neg Py\lor\neg Kxy$.  So the negation is: $$\exists x\exists y (Px\land Py\land Kxy)$$

Comment: Oh wow, that's fairly simple?! The section I got confused the most with was `Px∧Py` but thank you very much for your reply! Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well first recall that:

$
¬ (A \wedge B) \equiv  ¬A \vee ¬B \\
 A \rightarrow B \equiv ¬A \vee B
$

So,

$
¬ ( Px \wedge Py \rightarrow ¬Kxy) \equiv ¬( ¬(Px \wedge Py) \vee (¬Kxy) ) \equiv (Px \wedge Py) \wedge Kxy
$